# Problems with stacking div boxes vertically

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
.blueleft {
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    border: 25px #cee2e8;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 40px;
    float: left;
    font-family: "berlin sans fb";
    color: gray; 
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.blueright{
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    border: 25px #cee2e8;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 40px;
    float: right;
    font-family: "berlin sans fb";
    color: gray; 
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

However I still get the box elements stacked horizontally like this:

[image: Screenshot of current display]

I'm not sure what I need to do to make sure that the div boxes stack vertically, and still be able to format horizontally and centered if needed. I've been looking around but have been unable to find code that I could put into the html document.... how would I start from scratch when formatting the DIV elements in css?

Comment: Post your HTML please. We need a [mcve]. But the issue seems to be your use of floats

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want you could put    `display : block` to stack them vertically.

Comment: It seems the problem is that you floated your divs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I automatically stack divs vertically inside a parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284923/how-do-i-automatically-stack-divs-vertically-inside-a-parent)

Comment: @LucasWieloch I've already tried removing my float codes and even my margin codes.

Comment: @j08691 for the html I simply did <div class="blueleft"> and floated an image withing the div element, along with adding some text. For the other box element I tried both <div class="blueleft"> and <div class="blueright"> I also tried automatic and relative position tags but they didn't work either.

Comment: @VipulSharma All I'm trying to do is to get my div elements to flow vertically. I'm working on a mini website choose your own adventure type game and would like it to be formatted vertically for some of the website pages. Hopefully that clarifies it a little!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  height: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>
```